# Accessing multiple worksheets using excel 2013 vba

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, worksheet

I have 3 worksheets that I have data in. The main worksheet has a sheet named `Lists` that contains various lists for combo-boxes. I am trying to make the lists dynamic i.e. have the ability to add entries and have them show the next time the user goes to the combo-box on the user-form.

I have this code, which works fine ONLY if I'm in the `Lists` sheet of the correct workbook:

```
 ThisWorkbook.sheets("Lists").Range("I1", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "DriverList"
```

However, if I'm in another worksheet or another workbook (all in the same directory) I get a

> runtime error #1004.

I have tried both of the following lines with no success:

```
dim spath, sfile as string
dim wbCharityBins as Workbook
spath = "Z:\Charity Bins 2015 Test Data\"
sfile = "Charity Bins 2015 - test.xlsm"
Set wbCharityBins = Workbooks.(spath & sfile)
wbCharityBins.sheets("lists")... etc
```

or

```
Workbooks(spath & "Charity Bins 2015 - test.xlsm").sheets("Lists").Select
```

These two tries give:

> Subscript out of range, error 9

I have an initialization routine that opens all the workbooks before I get to the above problem, so the workbooks are open.

Any suggestions on how to access the worksheet from another sheet or workbook would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` which is referencing the range of the `ActiveSheet`, instead of "Lists".

Possible solution:

```
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lists")
    .Range("I1", .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "DriverList"
  End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial testing looks good.  Has the problem arisen because its a dynamic combo list?  When just passing data from a userform textbox should I be able to just use:

workbookx.sheets("y").range("a1") = userformTextBoxContents.

Remember all workbooks are open.